# Converting web3.sha3() bytes to string (Python)?

Tags: web3.py, python

The code I am having trouble with:

```
new_address = Web3.sha3(rlp.encode([normalize_address(accountAddress), nonce]))[-40:]
return '0x'+new_address
```

`new_adress` remains in bytes and I can't join it with 0x to produce normal string that will be the ethereum address. How to turn the bytes to string again? just `new_address.decode()` doesn't work and anything with utf-8 in it?

Answer (score 2):

What is coming from:

```
new_adress = Web3.sha3(rlp.encode([normalize_address(accountAddress), nonce]))[-40:]
```

is type bytes, so you can do:

```
new_adress = web3.toHex(Web3.sha3(rlp.encode([normalize_address(accountAddress), nonce])))[-40:]
return '0x'+ new_adress
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, I'll try now...bytes yes, well this is from an old program from university of singapore or so called "Maian", I'm trying to check if my contract is "suicidal" (can be killed by hackers). Long story short: they are using Web3, and Web3 has specific keyword "encoding", the "encoding" is in bytes...web3-v4 doesn't have that so I just removed it but the variable new_address is still in bytes I guess. wil let you know later, 10x again.